# Will my query be bottleneck for performance when data will be in GB/TB

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Hello in our app we have to provide analytics for all the details on analytics page i query database in one long query.

> This is my query here i have removed some fields as content was more than description limit. In my query it is full of subquery. There will
>   be morethan 20-30 subqueries in select statement. Is this right to
>   create query like this. Or i use some alternative of it. And yes data
>   is going to be increase day by day.
>
> **Is this right to have subqueries in select statement like this [in this amount] ?**

**MY QUERY [UPDATED 8-13-2015]**

```
SELECT COUNT(users.user_id),
   cards.card_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(users.user_id),
   GROUP_CONCAT(redeem_code.redeem_id),
   CASE
      WHEN cards.what_to_broadcast = "0"
      THEN
         "Information Card"
      WHEN cards.what_to_broadcast = "1"
      THEN
         "Rating Card"
      WHEN cards.what_to_broadcast = "2"
      THEN
         CASE
            WHEN cards.discount_type = "2"
            THEN
               "Price Cut Discount Card"
            WHEN cards.discount_type = "1"
            THEN
               "Buy X Get Y Discount Card"
            WHEN cards.discount_type = "0"
            THEN
               "Fixed Discount Card"
            ELSE
               "Fixed Discount Card"
         END
      WHEN cards.what_to_broadcast = "4"
      THEN
         CASE
            WHEN cards.question_type = "1"
            THEN
               "Multiple Choice Question Card"
            WHEN cards.question_type = "2"
            THEN
               "Single Choice Question Card"
            WHEN cards.question_type = "3"
            THEN
               "Discriptive Question Card"
            ELSE
               "Multiple Choice Question Card"
         END
      ELSE
         "Information Card x"
   END
      AS cardType,
   cards.name AS cardTitle,
   cards.what_to_broadcast,
   cards.card_id,
   COUNT(saved_card.saved_card_id) AS cardReach,
   COUNT(DISTINCT saved_card.redeem_id) AS cardReachCoupons,
   SUM((CASE WHEN saved_card.status = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
      AS sumOfSavedCard,
   SUM((CASE WHEN users.gender = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS maleRecipient,
   SUM((CASE WHEN users.gender = "2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
      AS femaleRecipient,
   SUM(
      (CASE
          WHEN saved_card.status = "1"
          THEN
             CASE WHEN users.gender = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ELSE
             0
       END))
      AS sumOfSavedCardMaleRecipient,
   SUM(
      (CASE
          WHEN saved_card.status = "1"
          THEN
             CASE WHEN users.gender = "2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ELSE
             0
       END))
      AS sumOfSavedCardFemaleRecipient,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.is_like = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS likers,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.is_like = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS maleLikersMain,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.is_like = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS femaleLikersMain,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS seenExtraInfo,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS maleSeenExtraInfo,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS femaleSeenExtraInfo,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT SUM(card_share.count) AS card_share
         FROM card_share
              INNER JOIN users ON card_share.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND card_share.status = "1"
              AND card_share.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS card_share_main,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT SUM(card_share.count) AS card_share
         FROM card_share
              INNER JOIN users ON card_share.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND card_share.status = "1"
              AND card_share.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS card_share_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT SUM(card_share.count) AS card_share
         FROM card_share
              INNER JOIN users ON card_share.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND card_share.status = "1"
              AND card_share.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS card_share_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS rate1,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS rate1_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "1"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS rate1_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "2"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS rate2,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "2"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS rate2_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "2"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS rate2_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "3"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS rate3,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "3"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS rate3_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "3"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS rate3_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "4"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS rate4,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "4"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS rate4_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "4"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS rate4_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "5"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id),
      0)
      AS rate5,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "5"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "1"),
      0)
      AS rate5_by_male,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(rating_like.rating_like_id)
         FROM rating_like
              INNER JOIN users ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     users.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.status = "1"
              AND rating_like.has_rated = "1"
              AND rating_like.rate = "5"
              AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND users.gender = "2"),
      0)
      AS rate5_by_female,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(redeem_code.redeem_id)
         FROM redeem_code
        WHERE     redeem_code.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND redeem_code.status = "1"),
      0)
      AS totalCoupons,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT redeem_code.redeem_id)
         FROM redeem_code
              INNER JOIN saved_card
                 ON saved_card.redeem_id = redeem_code.redeem_id
        WHERE     redeem_code.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND redeem_code.status = "1"
              AND redeem_code.used_coupon = "2"),
      0)
      AS totalRedeemCoupons,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT redeem_code.redeem_id)
         FROM redeem_code
              INNER JOIN saved_card
                 ON saved_card.redeem_id = redeem_code.redeem_id
              INNER JOIN users ON saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     redeem_code.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND redeem_code.status = "1"
              AND redeem_code.used_coupon = "2"
              AND users.user_id = "1"),
      0)
      AS maleRedeemCoupons,
   IFNULL(
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT redeem_code.redeem_id)
         FROM redeem_code
              INNER JOIN saved_card
                 ON saved_card.redeem_id = redeem_code.redeem_id
              INNER JOIN users ON saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE     redeem_code.card_id = cards.card_id
              AND redeem_code.status = "1"
              AND redeem_code.used_coupon = "2"
              AND users.user_id = "2"),
      0)
      AS femaleRedeemCoupons,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(options, "/~", cNum)
      FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                      DISTINCT COALESCE(card_question_options.value, ""))
                      AS options,
                   SUM(
                      CASE
                         WHEN saved_card_feedbacks.card_question_option_id =
                                 card_question_options.card_question_option_id
                         THEN
                            1
                         ELSE
                            0
                      END)
                      AS cNum,
                   c2.card_id
              FROM card_question_options
                   INNER JOIN cards c2
                      ON c2.card_id = card_question_options.card_id
                   INNER JOIN saved_card
                      ON     c2.card_id = saved_card.card_id
                         AND saved_card.status IN ("1", "2")
                   LEFT JOIN saved_card_feedbacks
                      ON     saved_card_feedbacks.saved_card_id =
                                saved_card.saved_card_id
                         AND saved_card_feedbacks.status = "1"
                   INNER JOIN users
                      ON     saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
                         AND users.status = "1"
             WHERE 1  AND card_question_options.status = "1"
            GROUP BY card_question_options.card_question_option_id)
           AS table1
     WHERE table1.card_id = cards.card_id)
      AS cardOptionsMain,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(options, "/~", cNum)
      FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                      DISTINCT COALESCE(card_question_options.value, ""))
                      AS options,
                   SUM(
                      CASE
                         WHEN saved_card_feedbacks.card_question_option_id =
                                 card_question_options.card_question_option_id
                         THEN
                            1
                         ELSE
                            0
                      END)
                      AS cNum,
                   c2.card_id
              FROM card_question_options
                   INNER JOIN cards c2
                      ON c2.card_id = card_question_options.card_id
                   INNER JOIN saved_card
                      ON     c2.card_id = saved_card.card_id
                         AND saved_card.status IN ("1", "2")
                   LEFT JOIN saved_card_feedbacks
                      ON     saved_card_feedbacks.saved_card_id =
                                saved_card.saved_card_id
                         AND saved_card_feedbacks.status = "1"
                   INNER JOIN users
                      ON     saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
                         AND users.status = "1"
                         AND users.gender = "1"
             WHERE 1  AND card_question_options.status = "1"
            GROUP BY card_question_options.card_question_option_id)
           AS table1
     WHERE table1.card_id = cards.card_id)
      AS cardOptionsMainMale,
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(options, "/~", cNum)
      FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                      DISTINCT COALESCE(card_question_options.value, ""))
                      AS options,
                   SUM(
                      CASE
                         WHEN saved_card_feedbacks.card_question_option_id =
                                 card_question_options.card_question_option_id
                         THEN
                            1
                         ELSE
                            0
                      END)
                      AS cNum,
                   c2.card_id
              FROM card_question_options
                   INNER JOIN cards c2
                      ON c2.card_id = card_question_options.card_id
                   INNER JOIN saved_card
                      ON     c2.card_id = saved_card.card_id
                         AND saved_card.status IN ("1", "2")
                   LEFT JOIN saved_card_feedbacks
                      ON     saved_card_feedbacks.saved_card_id =
                                saved_card.saved_card_id
                         AND saved_card_feedbacks.status = "1"
                   INNER JOIN users
                      ON     saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
                         AND users.status = "1"
                         AND users.gender = "2"
             WHERE 1   AND card_question_options.status = "1"
            GROUP BY card_question_options.card_question_option_id)
           AS table1
     WHERE table1.card_id = cards.card_id)
      AS cardOptionsMainFemale
  FROM cards
   INNER JOIN campaigns ON cards.camapign_id = campaigns.campaign_id
   INNER JOIN saved_card ON saved_card.card_id = cards.card_id
   INNER JOIN users ON saved_card.user_id = users.user_id
   LEFT JOIN redeem_code ON saved_card.redeem_id = redeem_code.redeem_id
WHERE     cards.status = "1"
   AND users.status = "1"
   AND saved_card.status IN ("1", "2")
   AND campaigns.campaign_id = :campaign_id
GROUP BY cards.card_id
```

In this query i retrive data for all the cards in one campaign.

1. campaign will have 20-30 cards. [cards table]
2. each card will be distributed to user [There is no limit over it. It will finish on campaign expiry date.] [saved_card table which will be related to users table]
3. Card may have redeem code .. so it can be also be 1 to N . There can be 500-1000 , or any number of redeem_coupons attached with card.  [reddem_code table ,  related to saved_card table which will be related to users table ]
4. And i am retriving data from other table which will have save_card_id as foreign key or card_id and user_id as foreign keys.

Comment: You probably should consider using coalesce instead of the case statements, it will simply the code greatly and may increase performance since the subquery won't have to generate twice. Not sure of that last because I don't know how mysql optimizes but it is something to try  nonetheless just for making the code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this will return about 20-30 rows per execution, and that the bulk of time is going to be spent in the sub-queries, I would predict that you will have inconsistent and disappointing response times *because* queries of this complexity are hard for most databases engines to establish a good execution plan for.   A simple but effective solution would be to convert the individual sub-queries into functions.  These the database engine would be able to optimize nicely, and you would also have a solution that is much easier to manage over the long term.

Comment: Additional thought :      An alternative to functions would be views ( quite possibly easier to write and use ).   In either case, make sure the best table indexes are going to be chosen so that performance is always good.

Comment: Ohk what about stored procedure for this ?

Comment: stored procedure / functions / views .. which can be best option ?

Comment: Ultimately, I would certainly suggest you package it up that way.  But, that wont help the SQL Engine in terms of optimizing the individual queries.  They are still better off in separate views or functions.   That is so both in terms of SQL optimization, and long term code maintenance.    So, the long term solution I would pursue is a stored proc to contain the driving query, and views or functions to embed the sub-queries.   There is no golden solution, but for queries such as yours, that approach has served me well.

Answer (score 1):

Lot of unnecessary expense here

consider

```
(SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN users.gender = "2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS femaleSeenExtraInfoInner
   FROM rating_like
   JOIN users
     ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
  WHERE users.status = "1"
    AND rating_like.status = "1"
    AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
    AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
  GROUP BY rating_like.card_id)
 IS NULL
```

Why all the work to test for a null?
Same result for  a LOT less work

```
(SELECT top 1 users.gender AS femaleSeenExtraInfoInner
       FROM rating_like
       JOIN users
         ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
        AND users.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
        AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id)
     IS NULL
```

Even if you do need a count

```
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN users.gender = "2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS femaleSeenExtraInfoInner
       FROM rating_like
       JOIN users
         ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id
      WHERE users.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
        AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
      GROUP BY rating_like.card_id
```

Why a group by rating_like.card_id?  You are joining on a single cards.card_id.

```
SELECT count(*) AS femaleSeenExtraInfoInner
       FROM rating_like
       JOIN users
         ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id 
        AND rating_like.card_id = cards.card_id
        AND users.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.status = "1"
        AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
        AND users.gender = "2"
```

or just make it a WHOLE lot simpler with

```
with cte_femaleSeenExtraInfoInner (card_id, count)
as 
(
  SELECT users.card_id, count(*) AS count
    FROM rating_like
    JOIN users
      ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id 
     AND users.status = "1"
     AND rating_like.status = "1"
     AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
     AND users.gender = "2"
   group by users.card_id
)
select distinct 
       cards.user_id, isnull(cte_femaleSeenExtraInfoInner.count, 0)
  FROM cards 
  left join cte_femaleSeenExtraInfoInner 
    on cte_femaleSeenExtraInfoInner.user_id = cards.user_id 
   ....
```

and you could even double up the gender with

```
SELECT users.card_id, users.gender, count(*) AS count
  FROM rating_like
  JOIN users
    ON rating_like.user_id = users.user_id 
   AND users.status = "1"
   AND rating_like.status = "1"
   AND rating_like.see_extra_info = "1"
   AND users.gender = in ("1", "2")
 group by users.card_id, users.gender
```

better yet materialize the cte to #temp so it is not evaluated multiple time

Comment: (`with` is not available in MySQL.)

Comment: @RickJames Shoot.  Is #temp available?    Can MySQL do inline / derived tables?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t SELECT ...;`  Then use `t` like any other table; `cte_femaleSeenExtraInfoInner` in your example.  Better yet, would be to do all the subqueries in a single pass with a big `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You cannot do all the subqueries in one pass as they have different conditions.  But could double up the gender ones.